# Use PostgreSQL plpython3u function to return a table

Tags: postgresql, plpython, postgres-plpython

I wanna return table.
The function get an array(the query is 'select function_name(array_agg(column_name)) from table_name')

I coded below:

```
create type pddesctype as(
    count float,
    mean float,
    std float,
    min float
);

create function pddesc(x numeric[])
returns pddesctype
as $$
    import pandas as pd
    data=pd.Series(x)
    
    count=data.describe()[0]
    mean=data.describe()[1]
    std=data.describe()[2]
    min=data.describe()[3]
    
    return count, mean, std, min

$$ language plpython3u;
```

This code results only array on one column.
(float, float, float...)

I tried

```
create function pddesc(x numeric[])
returns table(count float, mean float, std float, min float)
as $$
    import pandas as pd
    data=pd.Series(x)
    
    count=data.describe()[0]
    mean=data.describe()[1]
    std=data.describe()[2]
    min=data.describe()[3]
    
    return count, mean, std, min

$$ language plpython3u;
```

But there is an error:

```
ERROR:  key "count" not found in mapping
HINT:  To return null in a column, add the value None to the mapping with the key named after the column.
CONTEXT:  while creating return value.
```

I want to show the result in columns (like a table) without creating type in advance.

How to change the RETURN / RETURNS syntax?

Comment: if you want to return a table, then use `returns table (...)`

Comment: should i create table that a return value updated?

Comment: A function that returns a table must be used like a table `select * from pddesc(...)`

Comment: I need to get data from another table, so I tried `select * from (select pddesc(array_agg(column_name)) from table_name) as result`. However, I get array data on one column. Do you know another way to get table?

Comment: I deal with this question. I used plpy query in the python code. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I tried to get a table of one row with four columns as the Output. The last step has the solution, the first is another way to reproduce your error.

##### Check np.array

```
create or replace function pddesc(x numeric[])
returns table(count float, mean float, std float, min float)
as $$
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    data=pd.Series(x)

    count=data.describe()[0]
    mean=data.describe()[1]
    std=data.describe()[2]
    min=data.describe()[3]
    
    ## print an INFO of the output:
    plpy.info(np.array([count, mean, std, min]))

    return np.array([count, mean, std, min])

$$ language plpython3u;
```

Test fails (with the error of the question reproduced):

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pddesc(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
INFO:  [3 3 Decimal('1') 1]
ERROR:  key "count" not found in mapping
HINT:  To return null in a column, add the value None to the mapping with the key named after the column.
CONTEXT:  while creating return value
PL/Python function "pddesc"
```

##### Working solution: `np.array([...]).reshape(1,-1)`

You need to reshape the array so that it is of the dimension that you want to get. In this case, it is of dim (1 row x 4 cols), and the `.reshape(1,-1)` means 1 row and -1 (= whatever needed) cols

```
create or replace function pddesc(x numeric[])
returns table(count float, mean float, std float, min float)
as $$
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    data=pd.Series(x)

    count=data.describe()[0]
    mean=data.describe()[1]
    std=data.describe()[2]
    min=data.describe()[3]

    ## print an INFO of the output:
    plpy.info(np.array([count, mean, std, min]).reshape(1,-1))

    return np.array([count, mean, std, min]).reshape(1,-1)
    ## or with the same result:
    # return np.hstack((count, mean, std, min)).reshape(1,-1)

$$ language plpython3u;
```

Test:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pddesc(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
INFO:  [[3 3 Decimal('1') 1]]
 count | mean | std | min
-------+------+-----+-----
     3 |    3 |   1 |   1
(1 row)
```